# Get http in Flask

Tags: flask

I am starter to python and using Python Flask and generating REST API service.

I want to check authorization header which is sent the client.

But I can't find way to get HTTP header in flask.

Any help for getting HTTP header authorization is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about using basic HTTP Auth then you can get the username and password with Flask like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/route')
def route():
    username = request.authorization.username
    password = request.authorization.password
    ...
```

Be advised: [there are some security concerns when using basic HTTP Auth](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https)